# How to apply the Shapiro-Wilk Test on a specific data column in Python

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, trading, algorithmic-trading

I’d like to apply this test on the percent daily returns of SPY. After getting historical data of this symbol from Yahoo, I calculate the percent daily returns (as you can see on the below code). But when I apply the test the P value is always “1.00” and the return of the stats is always “nan”. No matter if I change the data dates or if I change the symbol (for example, QQQ instead SPY)

Below you can see the code that I’m using:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas_datareader as dr
from scipy.stats import shapiro

df = dr.data.get_data_yahoo('spy',start='2010-01-01',end='2015-01-01')
df['PCT'] = df['Close'].pct_change()

stat, p = shapiro(df['PCT'])
print('Statistics=%.3f, p=%.3f' % (stat, p))
```

Unfortunately I have tried different things but I couldn’t find the solution. I am stuck with it. Any idea about how to apply it correctly on the PCT column data?  Any help will be more than welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Step 1:** "when I apply the test the **P** value is always “`1.00`” and the return of the stats is always “**`nan`**”

No, sir, it is not.

```
print( 'Statistics\n(W)= %e,\n p = %e' % ( stat, p ) ) # will produce:
...    
(W)= 9.438160e-01
 p = 1.909053e-21
```

The core issue is, to respect how things work:

```
>>> df['PCT'] = df['Close'].pct_change() # this computes & stores .pct_change()
>>> df                                   # read print( df['Close'].pct_change.__doc__ )

                  High  ...       Close       Volume   Adj Close       PCT
Date                                                                                         
2010-01-04  113.389999  ...  113.330002  118944600.0   93.675278       NaN
2010-01-05  113.680000  ...  113.629997  111579900.0   93.923241  0.002647
2010-01-06  113.989998  ...  113.709999  116074400.0   93.989357  0.000704
2010-01-07  114.330002  ...  114.190002  131091100.0   94.386139  0.004221
2010-01-08  114.620003  ...  114.570000  126402800.0   94.700218  0.003328
...
```

Here, obviously, due to `period == 1` the cell `df['PCT'][0]` is and must be **`NaN`**

So, rather call **`W_stat, p_value = shapiro( df['PCT'][1:] )`** not to include a value that has no meaning w.r.t. the `shapiro()`

```
print( shapiro.__doc__ ) # for more details
```

Comparing values to the reference sample - the normal distribution test, where **there are no `NaN`-s** causes straight a must to reject the null-hypothesis **at being `p == 1` an absolutely sure rejection** ( which was obviously correct from the point of view of the two "incomparable-due-to-`NaN`(s)" sets compared ).

---

### Similarly `{ SPY | QQQ | AAPL | AMZN | ... }` :

```
>>> shapiro( dr.data.get_data_yahoo( 'SPY',
                                      start = '2010-01-01',
                                      end   = '2015-01-01'
                                      )['Close'].pct_change()[1:]
             )
(0.943816065788269, 1.9090532861060437e-21)

>>> shapiro( dr.data.get_data_yahoo( 'QQQ',
                                      start = '2010-01-01',
                                      end   = '2015-01-01'
                                      )['Close'].pct_change()[1:]
             )
(0.9631340503692627, 2.548133516564297e-17)

>>> shapiro( dr.data.get_data_yahoo( 'AAPL',
                                      start = '2010-01-01',
                                      end   = '2015-01-01'
                                      )['Close'].pct_change()[1:]
             )
(0.9560988545417786, 5.674560331738808e-19)

>>> shapiro( dr.data.get_data_yahoo( 'AMZN',
                                      start = '2010-01-01',
                                      end   = '2015-01-01'
                                      )['Close'].pct_change()[1:]
             )
(0.9394155740737915, 3.106424182886848e-22)
```